# WebKit cookies jar for OS X apps

Tags: macos, cookies, webkit, defaults

Is there a way to force a third party developed app for Mac OS X based on WebKit to not use the system/Safari shared cookies jar?

Some apps have an option for this. What I'm looking for is something similar to apply to apps which don't have it. Maybe there is a property you can set with the `defaults` command.